# Strange behavior for jQuery push() into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to push some elements into a 2d array
The code I am using is:

```
samount.push ({
        "value": val, 
        "currency": currency
    });
```

The array that I am trying to push into samount is like this:

```
groupedArray = 
     [{value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currencu: 'EUR'}]
```

In fact, the array above represents rows of one table, and at each row click, the push() function is adding do samount array a new element

After 2 row clicks, the samount array looks like:

```
samount = 
     [{value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currency: 'EUR'}]
```

At the third row click, the array becomes:

```
samount = 
     [{value: 200, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currencu: 'EUR'}]
```

I have to mention that my code has no sum inside, so it is very strange that the push() function is summing the values of first element and still is adding them to the array

Do you know if the push() function is ok for adding element to this type of arrays?

The complete code is:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {  
    var $dt = $('#dt_debts').footable({  
     breakpoints: { // The different screen resolution breakpoints  
         phone: 320,  
         tablet: 768  
     }   
    });  
    $dt.trigger('footable_resize');  

    var amount      = new Array();
    var samount     = new Array();  

    $('#dt_debts tbody tr ').each( function () {                            
        var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
        if (iPos!=null) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
            if (jQuery.inArray(aData[0], selected)!=-1) {
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                $(this).find( 'td input:checkbox' ).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }
        $(this).click( function (e) {   
            e.preventDefault();                     
            var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( iPos );
            var iId = aData[0];
            is_in_array = jQuery.inArray(iId, selected);
            if (is_in_array==-1) {
                selected[selected.length]=iId;
            }
            else {
                selected = jQuery.grep(selected, function(value) {
                    return value != iId;
                });
            }
            if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
                console.info('>>> Operatie de eliminare');
                $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
                $(this).find( 'td input:checkbox' ).prop('checked', false);
                if ($(aData[0]).data('typo') == "t-0") {
                    val = parseFloat(aData[9].split(" ")[0]);
                    currency = aData[9].split(" ")[1];
                    if (currency != '') {
                        $.each(amount, function(idx, item) {
                            if (item.currency == currency && item.value == val) {
                                amount.splice(idx, 1); // Remove current item
                                return false; // End the loop
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else if ($(aData[0]).data('typo') == "t-1") {
                    val = parseFloat(aData[10].split(" ")[0]);
                    currency = aData[10].split(" ")[1];
                    if (currency != '') {
                        $.each(samount, function(idx, item) {
                            if (item.currency == currency && item.value == val) {
                                samount.splice(idx, 1); // Remove current item
                                return false; // End the loop
                            }
                        });                                 
                    }                                       
                }
                console.info(amount);
                console.info(samount);
            } else {
                console.info('>>> Operatie de adaugare');
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');                                   
                $(this).find( 'td input:checkbox' ).attr('checked', 'checked');

                if ($(aData[0]).data('typo') == "t-0") {
                    val = parseFloat(aData[9].split(" ")[0]);
                    currency = aData[9].split(" ")[1];
                    if (currency != '') {
                        amount.push ({
                                "value": val, 
                                "currency": currency
                            });
                    }       
                } else if ($(aData[0]).data('typo') == "t-1") {
                    val = parseFloat(aData[10].split(" ")[0]);
                    currency = aData[10].split(" ")[1];
                    if (currency != '') {
                        samount.push ({
                                "value": val, 
                                "currency": currency
                            });
                    }       
                }
                console.info(amount);
                console.info(samount);                                  
            }
}
```

Aftre spending hours of searching the error, I have figured that the error is in this part of code:

```
var objects1 = new Array();
objects1 = samount;
var categories1 = new Array();
var groupedObjects1 = [];
var i = 0;

_.each(objects1,function(obj){
    var existingObj;

    if($.inArray(obj.currency,categories1) >= 0) {
        existingObj = _.find(objects1,function(o){return o.currency === obj.currency;});
        existingObj.value += obj.value;
    } else {
        groupedObjects1[i] = obj;
        categories1[i] = obj.currency;
        i++;
    }
});// JavaScript Document
```

Actually it seems that the **samount** array is beeing modified even if I have declared a new array for using into loop. I do not understand why the loop is modifying the initial array, even if I am not using it

Comment: Please show more of the surrounding code that gets the `value`.  Also, it isn't clear exactly what you want help with.  What result are you seeing?  And, what are you expecting it to be?

Comment: So you're saying push sums up the value when pushing? Any chance you can recreate that in a Fiddle.

Comment: I guess that recreating this on Fiddle is most likely impossible, because of the large code structure.. You are right when you say that when pushing the array the values are summed after second row click..

Comment: I am using jQuery Datatables with fnDrawCallback, and on each row click I am pushing values from table to an array

Comment: Well, push() doesn't sum up values inside an object, so I was thinking it would be impossible to recreate, that's why I asked. Something else is going on, just pushing has nothing to do with this.

Comment: There is nothing  wrong in push (http://jsfiddle.net/WY56W/ -fiddle for example).Something is wrong in your code,provide your complete code regarding this issue .

Comment: I have just edited the post with the complete code

Comment: Are you reusing an object anywhere in your code rather than creating a new object?  Objects are put into arrays as references to reusing the same object will actually modify the one already in the array.  Can't tell any of this without seeing more of the surrounding code.

Comment: And I still cannot understand WHY am I penalised for asking a legit question! If someone is offended by the question I guess that he's got the solution and thinks that the answer is so obvious that it can be shared with all the rest

Comment: @rosuandreimihai - I didn't downvote your question, but you shouldn't get so bothered by it.  That stuff happens routinely here on SO.  If you ask good questions and supply good answers, you will get more upvotes than downvotes, but you will still occasionally get a downvote. Continued in next comment...

Comment: A better question to ask is to ask why someone gave you a downvote?  My guess is because your question simply isn't very clear and you did not include enough context for us to understand what might be happening.  That means our only option is to guess and questions that simply don't contain enough info except to guess are not great questions.  Even now that you have added more code, it is still very difficult to follow your code or understand where exactly your issue is occurring.  I know this is hard sometimes, but you have to remember that we have zero context about your code or the problem.

Comment: ...And `.push()` doesn't add elements to the top of the array, it is adding elements at the end of parent array. So this is not an error with `.push()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, push is fine. Indeed I tested it and it works as it is supposed to. What I assume is happening is the value being modified somewhere else - since you are pushing an object into the array with the value `val` the array would only hold a reference to the entire thing **not** the values it represents.

Just to illustrate this

```
var val = { "value" : 100 };
var storage = [ ];

storage.push(val);


console.log("value  : " + val.value);
console.log("value in storage : " + storage[0]["value"]);

val.value = 200;

console.log("value  : " + val.value);
console.log("value in storage : " + storage[0]["value"])
```

yields

```
value  : 100
value in storage : 100
value  : 200
value in storage : 200
```

The variables in JavaScript are pass by value for primitives (e.g., integers) but pass by reference for objects.

Comment: I assume you meant to say "pass-by-reference", but that would be incorrect. JS is *always* "pass-by-value". "pass-by-reference" is something else: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_reference#Call_by_reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.join()` instead of `.push()`

```
 //if you want the ful array as a single element:
    groupedArray = 
         [{{value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
          {value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
          {value: 100, currencu: 'EUR'}}];

    samount.join(groupedArray);


//if you want each element in groupedArray as elements in samount:
groupedArray = 
     [{value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currency: 'EUR'},
      {value: 100, currencu: 'EUR'}];

samount.join(groupedArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after hours of searching in code for errors, I have figured that the eror lies in one loop. I will edit my post to mention where the error is, and still I do not have any clue about how to solve it

Comment: There is an array called `_`(Underscore) I guess. look that